# Creating cookies in javascript and use it into mvc 4 action result

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have make cookies in java script page but when used in the Controller page it shows null and i Check in the browser cookies is also created so please help me for this ......

```
<script>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.CallJSFuncOnPageLoad)
    function IPDetction()
    {
        $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, val)
            {
                if (key == 'city') {
                    document.cookie = "DetectedCityName=" + val;
                }
                if (key == 'region') {
                    document.cookie = "DetectedRegionName=" + val;
                }
            });
        });
    }
    </script>

    @{
    string DetectedCityName = "Toronto";
    try
    {
        RateMadnessfinal.DataModel.RateMadnessdbEntities db = new RateMadnessfinal.DataModel.RateMadnessdbEntities();
        DetectedCityName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["DetectedCityName"].Value;   
        var getCityID = db.Macities.Where(c => c.CityName.Contains(DetectedCityName)).ToList();
        if ((getCityID != null) && (getCityID.Count > 0))
        {
            DetectedCityName = getCityID.FirstOrDefault().CityName;
        }
        else
        {
            DetectedCityName = "Toronto";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DetectedCityName = "Toronto";
    }
}
```